# Use Task in FMX loose transparent

Tags: delphi, task, firemonkey, transparent

My Android application is a little big, and when I launch it to my phone I need to wait 3-5 seconds.

So I decided to use TTask.
In my FormCreate event I use a TTask to load my Database to a personnal class.

When loading is finnish I load item on a TListBoxItem.

I got a problem, all background of my TImage are black, same for text and other objects.

[image]

The black rectangle with write "+2 Voir tout" is with a Opacity of 0.5, and then here it's all black.

```
TTask.Run(procedure
 begin
  Gestionnaire := TGestionnaire.Create(Cnx);

  TThread.Queue(nil,
                procedure
                begin
                   ChargerHomePage;
                   TabControl.ActiveTab := tabHome;
                   aniindicator1.Enabled := false;
                end);
 end);
```